# Is POST method idempotent if backend does't allow duplicates?

Tags: rest, post, unique, idempotent

Usualy POST is not idempotent.
But let's consider a situation when a POST method sends user/password/password and a backend-app registers a new user. 
Users are unique, that's why the same POST  method (with the same data) doesn't effect the server. A new user is not created for the second time. In this case is the POST method idempotent or not?

Answer (score 2):

> A new user is not created for the second time. In this case is the POST method idempotent or not?

Is *that* POST handler idempotent?  Yes, it sounds like it is.  It certainly can be.

That said; a general purpose client isn't going to know that this *particular* handler happens to have an idempotent implementation.  The point of a uniform interface is that the message semantics, and the corresponding guarantees, are the same everywhere.

A general purpose client can't assume that *your* POST handler is idempotent because the [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) says that *my* POST handler doesn't have to be.

> So what should I do if my database doesn't allow duplicates? I have to break the standard, correct?

No, what you are doing is fine, and doesn't break the standard.  The standard doesn't forbid an implementation of POST from being idempotent; it says that clients can't *assume* that the operation is idempotent.

It's exactly analogous to "safe", in this respect: the standard doesn't promise that POST requests are safe, so client's aren't allowed to assume that they will be.  But it is still compliant for us to use POST for safe requests, which is why we can do things like use POST for SOAP/GraphQL queries.

Comment: So what should I do if my database doesn't allow duplicates? I have to break the standard, correct?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST method by standard definition is in fact IS NOT idempotent. However it will always be based on the actual backend server implementation that POST will be idempotent.

Apparently REST is not a strict standard but rather more of a guideline on how to build a *RESTful* API, so to speak.

As for your specific case, YES, POST method IS idempotent.

Comment: Why not? Usually it IS NOT idempotent, but in my specific case it doesn't create entity  for the 2nd time, only the first call affect the system (similar to get, put). That's why it does become idempotent.